# Can i populate a database from another database

Tags: mysql, database, data-warehouse

I'm trying to create a data warehouse.

Is it possible to populate a table in db1, from data in db2.

For example

Corporate Database Table Route

```
CREATE TABLE ROUTE (
RouteID INTEGER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
RouteName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
BoardingStop VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
AlightingStop VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert Information

```
INSERT INTO `ROUTE` (`RouteID`,`RouteName`,`BoardingStop`,`AlightingStop`)
VALUES (1,"ab","B","C")
```

Data warehouse table dimRoute

```
CREATE TABLE DimROUTE (
RouteID INTEGER(4),
RouteName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
BoardingStop VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
AlightingStop VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(RouteID)
);
```

Populate the above table with data from the first table.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't copy tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy from one table into another table with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. See docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

You can copy between tables in different databases on the same MySQL instance, provided you have privileges to both database. Just use `databasename.tablename` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO warehouse.DimRoute
  SELECT * FROM corporate.Route;
```

If the databases are hosted on different MySQL instances, you can dump data from the corporate instance and import to the data warehouse instance using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). Since your table is named differently in the data warehouse, this is a little bit tricky.

You could restore the data to its original table name, and then rename the table:

```
$ mysqldump --host=corporate corp_dbname ROUTE > route-dump.sql
$ mysql --host=datawarehouse dw_dbname < route-dump.sql
$ mysql --host=datawarehouse -e "RENAME TABLE ROUTE TO DimROUTE" dw_dbname
```

(I'm leaving out user/password options for brevity, but I suggest you use the config file for those.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a couple of queries to clone a table (with its indexes and keys) then populate it with the records:

```
CREATE TABLE DimROUTE LIKE ROUTE; 
INSERT DimROUTE SELECT * FROM ROUTE;
```

[Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3887/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  The technique you want is called [Extract, Transform and Load (ETL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).  There are a number of tools you can use, which will help you automate and organise the process.  Or you can roll your own solution.

It is quite common for reporting databases to be feed by other databases in this fashion.